# Is it worth spending extra on R14 or R20 fiberglass insulation

Tags: insulation, fiberglass

I've put in 1" Type 1 polystyrene (estimated at R3.75) around the exterior walls and I'm deciding which insulation to use in the framing.

The R12 works out to $.38 p/sqft
The R14 works out to $.54 p/sqft (+40% over R12)
The R20 works out to $.63 p/sqft (+65% over R12, + 17% over R14)

I need about 500 sqft of this stuff. The different R values come in different size packages, so that could come into play in terms of the cost difference.

**Is it worth to spend 40%, or 65% more on the insulation batts?** With R12 and the polystyrene, I've got over R15. But more insulation means more $aving on heating.

Comment: You need a lot more information to calculate this - climate, square footage, energy cost, etc.  Luckily you can use the [Insulation Investment Calculator](http://chuck-wright.com/calculators/insulpb.html) ;-)

Comment: It depends on your climate and how much you spend on heating/cooling. But since you're only talking about $125 difference between the R12 and R20, it wouldn't take long to make up the difference in savings on your utility bill -- if you lower your heating/cooling bill by $1/month you'd make up the savings after 10 years. Lower it by $10/month and you'd make up the savings in one year.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just realized that R20 comes in 6", and my framing is using 2x4s. So really it's just between R12 and R14 now

Comment: You might want to also talk to your municipality's code enforcement division. I know where I live there are minimum R-value requirements for insulation on exterior walls, there may be similar requirements where you live.